# Custom ArrayList class

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm building a priority queue for a school project.

I'm using an `ArrayList` for my `Queue`, the position 0 being the head of my Queue and `list.size()` being the end.

I was given an interface with a bunch of methods to define in my class, which I did.

However, I'm also supposed to create a constructor for `FilePrio` (Which would create a object of type `FilePrio`, which is a queue represented in memory with an ArrayList).

My constructor is :

```
public filePrio() { 
  filePrio<T> filePrio = new filePrio<T>();
}
```

I don't think this is right, but I'm not sure.

In one of the methods, `public void enfilerTous(IFilePrio<T> filePrio)`

I get a **filePrio** and I have to put the elements in that list in the one from the class. However, I cannot make calls like

```
priorite1 = getPriorite(filePrio.get(i)) ;
```

because it isn't an ArrayList? Is there a way for me to make my `FilePrio` into an ArrayList? I know there's something I'm not getting here but I'm not sure what it is!

Comment: No, that makes no sense. If you construct a FilePrio every time you construct a FilePrio, you'll have an endless recursion. Please respect the basic Java naming conventions. This should be mastered long before even touching generics. If FilePrio uses an ArrayList, then its constructor should probably create an ArrayList, not another FilePrio.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing `Comparable<class>`, then you will be able to add some objects to your list. Overriding of `compareTo(object)` will be needed then.